# How to handle multiple external configs?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot has `ConfigurationProperties` annotation which makes it easy to load the config in `application.properties` into a strongly typed Java class. I have a project with multiple classes that can serve as `main`. These classes also expect different configs i.e., `Class1` wants a `Config1`, `Class2` would like to have a different `Config2`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
class Config1 {
}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties
class Config2 {
}
```

but when I try to do this, Spring Boot tries to load `application.properties` into each of the configs. How can I tell it to load `application.properties` only for the config class for which its meant to be used?

Comment: Why not working with different spring-profiles and attach them to the different configs? General config at the general file and split them up for others. Just need to make sure that you have activated the correct profiles for the correct usecases. (Keep in mind that the order of profiles matters on overwriting redundent properties).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `prefix` in the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. Then, it will only pick up properties starting with that prefix:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("config.first")
class Config1 {
}
@ConfigurationProperties("config.second")
class Config2 {
}
```

and in your `application.properties`:

```ini
# properties for Config1
config.first.your_config_1_property = value1

# properties for Config2
config.second.your_config_2_property = value2
```

Comment: this does not work because as I suspected spring boot still tries to load both Config1 and Config2 from application.properties and that causes error in my application when application.properties only has values for Config1 as example; the validation of Config2 fails. the expected behavior is that I should be able to tell spring boot to load only either Config1 or Config2 from application.properties.

Comment: That is not how the approach provided by my answer works. Noth configs are supposed to be loaded from any application.properties that's there. You just need to specify a different prefix for the properties inside the application.properties. Mentally, you could imagine all application.properties to/configuration be merged together into a single file at startup. But as long as you consistently use different prefixes, these shouldn't interfere.